# gRPC connection cycling

Tags: java, grpc, tensorflow-serving, grpc-java

We are setting up a cluster to handle inferencing (with Tensorflow Serving) over gRPC.  We intend to use a layer-7 load balancer (AWS ALB) to distribute the load.  For our work load, inferencing will occur many times per minute from each client account.  It is my understand that gRPC holds connection state for each of these channels.  As a result, in order for the ALB to do its job, we need to periodically teardown and rebuild the connection on the client instance.

My question: what is the best practice for cycling a connection in Java?

Below is my proposed code, which would be called every couple minutes on each client channel.  I *assume* that while the first connection is being shutdown, we can go about creating new one and immediately issue a request on it; or do we need to wait while the prior channel is shutdown first.  In our situation, the channel will (very likely) be empty since the previous request will have been 10 seconds earlier.

```
        if (mChannel != null) 
            mChannel.shutdown();
        
        mChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(mHost, mPort).usePlaintext().build();
        mStub    = PredictionServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(mChannel);
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement client-side load balancing from [here](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing/#proxy-or-client-side)?

Comment: Yes.  Many client machines going through a single LB to a cluster of instances handling inferencing.  We have the freedom to update our client side code to provide connection cycling, so that made the most sense (at least to me).

Comment: When using an L7 proxy, you shouldn't need heavy connection cycling (other than to load balance the _proxy_). With an L7 proxy, each RPC can go to a different backend.

Comment: I was incorrect.  We are using Server-side load-balancing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use [Lookaside Load Balancing](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing/#lookaside-load-balancing).

However, you can do few tweaks to terminate client connections.

```
var builder = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(mHost, mPort)
.keepAliveTime(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.keepAliveTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The above config will ensure to terminate sticky gRPC connections, and AWS ALB can do its job to load balance requests uniformly.

There are other options that you can try depending upon your use case, e.g retries, etc. See [ManagedChannelBuilder](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for!