# Resolution of Server IPs in gRPC

Tags: java, grpc, channel, grpc-java

We are running a setup on production where grpc clients are talking to servers via proxy in between (image attached)

[image: production setup]

The client is written in java and server is written in go. We are using the load balancing property as round_robin in the client. Despite this, we have observed some bizarre behaviour. When our proxy servers scale in i.e reduce from let's say 4 to 3, then resolver gets into action and the request load from our clients gets distributed equally to all of our proxies, but when the proxy servers scale out i.e increase from 4 to 8, then the new proxy servers don't get any requests from the clients which leads to a skewed distribution of request load on our proxy servers. Is there any configuration that we can do to avoid this?

We tried setting a property named `networkaddress.cache.ttl` to 60 seconds in the JVM ARGS but even this didn't help.

Comment: How does the client know to use the proxy? Mostly equivalently: Is that an L4 proxy or a HTTP CONNECT "client-side" proxy?

Comment: @EricAnderson It is a L7 Proxy i.e Kong.

Comment: In that case the clients only see the proxy's IP(s). round_robin would be cycling between the proxies. Scaling up/down the service has no impact to the client. Maybe you intended to use pick_first on the client and round robin within the proxy?

Comment: @EricAnderson Yes, the clients are seeing the proxy IPs only. I am talking about the case where the proxy boxes scale out. The connections should get established with the new proxy boxes right ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. gRPC clients refresh DNS when a connection closes. So you can cycle connections occasionally from the proxy. Which proxy are you using? Ideally there'd be an option like gRPC's MAX_CONNECTION_AGE.

Comment: Thanks @EricAnderson . Any plans to provide a polling based mechanism for handling newly scaled up boxes? I saw similar issues being reported related to the same on the grpc-java repository ([link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2514)) 

Setting MAX_CONNECTION_AGE would solve the problem in the short run but still it would result in connection churn. For organisations using grpc at a large scale, I think this would be a very common problem.

Comment: The complaint about connection churn seems premature optimization and has not actually been demonstrated to be a problem. Amoritized, the cost of the connection churn is low, and much lower than would have been seen in HTTP/1. At scale it has the very strong advantage that the proxy owner is in control of the refresh rate.

Answer (score 1):

both `round_robin` and `pick_first` perform name resolution only once. They are intended for thin, user-facing clients (android, desktop) that have relatively short life-time, so sticking to a particular (set of) backend connection(s) is not a problem then.

If your client is a server app, then you should be rather be using `grpclb` or the newer [xDS](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A27-xds-global-load-balancing.md): they automatically re-resolve available backends when needed. To enable them you need to add runtime dependency in your client to `grpc-grpclb` or `grpc-xds` respectively.
`grpclb` does not need any additional configuration or setup, but has limited functionality. Each client process will have its own load-balancer+resolver instance. backends are obtained via repeated DNS resolution by default.
`xDS` requires an external envoy instance/service from which it obtains available backends.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cycle the sticky gRPC connections using the **keepalive** and **keepalive timeout** configuration in the gRPC client.

Please have a look at this - [gRPC connection cycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609655/grpc-connection-cycling/67646817#67646817)